# About slices in Python

Tags: python, slice

1. Is there any difference between `mylist[:]` and `mylist[::]`?
2. What's the rationale for `mylist[::0]` to raise an error since negative steps are allowed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. No. Both result in `slice(None, None, None)`.
2. Positive strides go forwards. Negative strides go backwards. Zero strides go... nowhere? How exactly would that work? An infinite sequence of a single value?

Comment: You could perhaps add an explanation about `slice` objects. At least see `help(slice)` :)

Comment: actually I would expect to get either a None object or a 0 length array back on a 0 length slice

Answer (score 1):

```
No difference between mylist[:] and mylist[::]

mylist[::0]
```

This implies from starting index to last index without any step, don't know in what world it would be possible.

Comment: The explicit zero makes you think, "No-one would ever do that", but if the value had been calculated instead it wouldn't be possible to spot, and I can imagine it happening.

Answer (score 0):

Third element is for steps. When you write `mylist[:]` it will assume step will be 1 which is same case in `mylist[::]`.

If you write `mylist[::0]` then it will raise error because steps can be `+ve` or `-ve` not `0`

Comment: They can be 0, it's just that a 0 stride is meaningless.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, >>> [1,2,3,4,5][::0]
ValueError: slice step cannot be zero

Comment: That exception comes from `list`, not `slice`.